# How to detect reason of "Terminating app due to uncaught exception" error?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm working on card game (turn based) and I have one problem. When I'm in the game, I click on home button to exit the game and then I enter the game again and I get this error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception...

How can I detect reason and place of this error? Is there any method or settings in xcode for that?

My Xcode version: 4.5.2

I get this error on my iPhones (4S and 5), bit not when I try on iPhone simulator.

P.S. With PHP errors are simple because for example you get thid: there is an error on line: 45

**Update**. The error is:

> [ViewController interruption:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c54d260

Comment: Please post the error.  Also, xcode's exception breakpoint is a valuable tool.  Go to breakpoints tab (6th item at the top of the righthand navigation) and add one '+' sign lower right.

Comment: See [exception breakpoints](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html).

Comment: @danh - error is "Terminating app due to uncaught exception in ViewController

Comment: Still need more in order to help... can you paste the actual error message from the console?  Can you set a breakpoint in appDidBecomeActive and see how much you can step through?  Can you set the exception breakpoint and see where you are in your code when it's thrown? etc.

Comment: I have added detailed explanation, I don't understand why would anybody downvote my question.

Comment: @danh - updated my first post